# How to capture a check box input element in Java script?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```html
<form name="formname">
  <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="user_name" id="user_input"></input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="website_response[]" value="I really like your site" id="checkbox">I like your site</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="website_response[]" value="One of the best site">One of the best site</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="website_response[]" value="good site">Good Site</input>
  <input type="checkbox" name="website_response[]" value="I wish my site were good">I wish my site were good</input>
</form>
```

The above code conatins name attribute as an array. How do I access it in Javascript?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, inputs are self closing so the `</input>` should be omitted

Comment: Why exactly do you have the name be the same for all of these (except the first `<input>`)? Do you expect something different to happen when you have `[]` at the end of a `name` attribute? because there isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `name` attribute of the checkboxes using the following :

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
var names = [];
checkboxes.forEach(elem => {
    names.push(elem.name);
});
```

If you only want the `name` attribute of the checkbox which is checked you can use :

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
var names = [];
checkboxes.forEach(elem => {
    if(elem.checked) {
        names.push(elem.name);
    }
});
```